# Django Template linebreaks inside textarea tag

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a variable with linebreaks, and am trying to insert it inside a textarea tag.

```
<textarea>{{ var_name }}</textarea>
```

I want the line breaks to be preserved so that it looks the same as when the variable is displayed

```
<div>{{ var_name|linebreaks }}</div>
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Was able to solve this by replacing the \n to html code:

```
stringname.replace("\n", "&#10");
```

Comment: That is what the `escape` filter does: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#escape. So you could just do `<textarea>{{ var_name|escape }}</textarea>`.

Answer (score 1):

Within text area, `\n` appear as line breaks. As long as line breaks within your variable are encoded as `\n`, it should appear properly. If they are encoded differently, you can make your own custom template filter.

**PS**: Don't use [`linebreaks`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#linebreaks) filter within text area because it replaces `\n` with html line break - `<br>`.

Comment: They are \n but will not display in the template. I have tried using the |safe but they still will not show up. When I print in console the string is displayed with line breaks but not in the HTML

Comment: If you open html page source, does the text inside textarea span multiple lines?

Comment: Also are you using any html minification, either middleware, or `{% spaceless %}`?

Comment: text also appears on one line

Comment: so somewhere between the view and the rendered template new lines are removed. have no idea where though.

Comment: Try setting something simple in `get_context_data` like `{'test_text': 'hi\nthere'}`, and print that into the textarea. The problem may be pre-view.

Comment: Was able to solve this by replacing the \n to html code:     stringname.replace("\n", "&#10");